# Moving assets for a client-side game out into a separate Git repository

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I made a simple, DOM-based visual novel-like game in HTML/CSS/JS. It runs purely on the client-side on GH-Pages. The repo currently looks like this:

```
/characters
  /npc1
    (assets like images and scripts for this NPC character)
  /npc2
/src
  /scripts
  /css
index.html
```

Players can create their own NPCs by providing their own images, dialogue, quest details, etc... When completed, I add them to the game so they're available to everyone else. I provide instructions on how to fork the game's repo, work on a character, and do a pull request.

Occasionally, typos and bugs need to be fixed. Sometimes players want their NPCs to interact with new ones. Git is invaluable for this, since dialogue files and scripts can be improved even after being added to the game. For the most part, the images stay the same.

As more characters are added, all the images (there are several thousand now) begin to bloat the repo, especially the .git folder.

I'm thinking about extracting the "characters" folder out into its own repository. That way, I can keep the core game code separate from player-created content.

**My question is, what's the best way to do this?**

Here are the things I've considered:

- **Git submodules**: I've looked at Git submodules, but they seem pretty complicated. I want the players to be able to create their own characters with minimal hassle.
- **Git subtrees**: Doesn't really solve the repo size issue.
- **Using a database / host**: GH-Pages is static files only, and I don't really want to spend money for a server on a personal project. A DB will also take away the review/improve process in Git for characters.
- **Have the game repo fetch characters from the character repo**: This might work (not sure yet), but wouldn't it just bloat the character repo?

Does anyone have a better idea, or can tell me which is most suitable?

My main priorities are

1. Finding a solution to the repo size problem that will scale to many characters
2. Maintaining the game code and the characters separately
3. Making it easy for players to develope their own characters